# Google Sheets: Text result of JOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet that has a few thousand rows and two columns in this format:

| Email | No of tickets |
| --- | --- |
| test@test.com | 1 |
| example@example.com | 7 |

I have a formula that repeats each email address on its own row n times (where n=No of tickets). So in the example above test@test.com would e printed on 1 row, example@example.com would be printed on 7 rows...

The formula that works is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("", ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(A2:A&"♦", B2:B))), "♦")))
```

However, if there are too many rows of data in the input table then I get the error: "Text result of JOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters."

Are there any ways around this limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Δ,index(match(,0/(A:A<>""))),
     tocol(map(A2:index(A:A,Δ),B2:index(B:B,Δ),lambda(Σ,Λ,if(or(Σ="",Λ=""),,wraprows(Σ,Λ,Σ)))),1))
```

Comment: That formula works, but like the original formula I was using, it seems to cap out at over about 800 rows of input data. It throws the following error: Error
Reference does not exist.

Comment: Hopefully someones else with pitch in with an alternative. If possible do share a test sheet(dummy data) *recreating this error scenario* so that we can test directly and all. you can also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) if needed to share a sheet

Comment: Here's a link to a sheet using randomly generated email addresses: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jd-mNAchTTpfPkPDAq3v7sfygRNKPefCiU4xx5vMIfI/edit#gid=2100307022 - It works great when 'Total emails in list' is under about 3,000 but then breaks when it gets higher. In the real world, my sheet will have about 13,000 rows.

Comment: Apologies, I just noticed you updated your answer, I've used that and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in Scripts - just use a getRange() & getValues() approach and then setValues() where ever you want them printed. You can tie the action to an event so you can run on command.